# Создание пустого массива NumPy и постепенное его заполнение

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

На данный момент программа постепенно записывает в пустой список большой объём данных. Делает примерно так:

```
import time

# Создаю пустые списки
z_gyro_row = []  
collect_time_row = []  
START_TIME = time.time()
  
# В цикле по определённому условию считываю данные с датчика
# И постепенно заполняю пустые списки
while flag:
            collect_time = time.time() - START_TIME  # Фиксируем отрезок времени
            collect_time_row.append(collect_time)  # Запись времени в список
            z_gyro_32 = gyro_out32(z_gyro_32)  # Считываю значение с датчика
            z_gyro_row.append(z_gyro_32)  # Запись значений в список
```

На один из моих вопросов, мне посоветовали для большого объёма данных использовать массивы NumPy. Сейчас я это попытался сделать, но как я понимаю их невозможно так же как и списки постепенно заполнять данными с помощью команды .append.
Попытался так, но не вышло:

```
import numpy as np

my_array = np.array([], 'float64')
np.append(my_array, 10)
```

Возможно только преобразовать list в numpy.ndarray. В связи с этим возникает вопрос как оптимально использовать массивы NumPy, чтобы тратить как можно меньше времени и ресурсов на запись/хранение/обработку данных?

Comment: `my_array = np.append(my_array, 10)`

Comment: @strawdog Спасибо, всё работает!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, массивы -  неизменяемый (не расширяемый) тип данных. Это цена за скорость работы. Вообще-то ничего нового и страшного: классические массивы в том-же С++ именно так и работают. Уже десятки лет. И еще столько-же будут использоваться и работать.

Теперь что делать. Самое худшее из возможных решений - работать с ними как со списками, т.е. порождать пустым, а потом добавлять по мере необходимости по одному элементу.  Разумный путь - определить максимально возможное (в будущем) количество элементов в массиве, порождать массив именно такого размера, а потом заполнять его элементы по мере их появления. Промежуточный путь  -  породить массив большого (достаточного на первое время функционирования) размера, после исчерпания  -  добавлять новый фрагмент (опять - не на один элемент, конечно).

Поскольку у вас работа идет -  мне так кажется -  с датчиками, то у вас еще меньше проблем  должно возникнуть, если конечно архитектуру приложения разработать нормально. В таких приложениях -  нет необходимости хранить информацию бесконечно долго. Более того, есть такое понятие - окно наблюдения. По сути, сколько данных вы обрабатываете. И это окно как правило коненчо. Вот и создавайте массив соответствующего размера. Или два таких массива - один заполняется, данные из второго - обрабатываются. Кстати - заполнять можно действительно через список, который по только факту полного заполнения преобразуется в массив.  Потом массивы меняются местами -  второй наполняется, первый обрабатывается.  Но архитектуру конечно надо при этом делать не спонтанно-интуитивно.

Comment: Я точно знаю, что датчик не может выдавать более 4250 значений в секунду, а вот как долго я буду считывать данные - это всегда разные величины, так как считывание продолжается пока вращается привод. Поэтому заранее определить размерность сложно. Но если бы я знал размерность массива, с помощью какой команды можно создать массив соответствующего размера, чтобы потом постепенно его заполнять?

Comment: Да, можно.  Команда - любая - np.empty(), np.zeros()... их там больше десятка на все случаи жизни.  Но сами эти команды проблемы (по взрослому) не решают. Поймите, решение вашей задачи - не программное, а архитектурное. Вы же согласитесь, что если датчик будет беспрерывно вращаться годами -  то вы не станете все данные по 4250 значений за секунду за несколько лет хранить. Это предельный пример, но он показывает суть. Считали информацию за 10 секунд (или 20, или 1000, или.....) , обработали, если надо хранить - записали в файл. Пока обрабатываете или записываете - набираете второй массив и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваше объяснение, многое прояснилось. Но я так и не понял, как можно в NumPy создать массив определённой размерности, а потом заполнять его данными. Единственное, что приходит в голову - это создать единичный массив (`ones = np.ones((4250, 1), np.float64)`) , но как потом заменять единицы моими данными с датчиками?

Comment: @leach Так просто обращаясь по индексу: `ones[i] = x`

Comment: @leach А вы какой нибудь учебник или документацию по numpy читать не пробовали? Очень помогает. В вашем случае, создаете массив  one=np.ones(4250,np.float64). Записываете на произвольное место нужное вам значение: one[747]=0.35465

Answer (score 3):

Если данных не очень много (не миллионы значений), то вам вообще не имеет смысла мучиться с `Numpy`. Я потестил ради интереса, создал пустой список из добавил к нему по одному 1 000 000 (миллион) элементов. На это у питона ушло 100 миллисекунд.

Если такая скорость для вас мала, то тогда нужно выделять массив `Numpy`, например, с помощью `np.empty` заведомо большего размера, чем вам может понадобится, и заполнять его, обращаясь к элементам по индексу. Но это не так удобно, как работать со списком.

А ещё в питоне есть разные виды очередей, например, очень удобная `collections.deque`, которую можно читать и писать с обоих концов. Если вы то пишете в список, то читаете из него вперемешку, то использовать очередь ещё проще и удобнее, чем список. Опять же на примере миллиона элементов создание очереди путём добавления элементов с конца и с начала по очереди, а потом полное опустошение очереди опять же забиранием элементов с конца и с начала по очереди заняло чуть больше тех же 100 миллисекунд. Очень рекомендую очередь - весьма удобная коллекция.

Comment: В принципе, вы правы. Вся прелесть numpy проявляется не тогда, когда вы массив создаете, а когда начинаете с ним работать. Вот тогда -  и обработка может оказаться на много быстрее чем в списке,   код проще и убодочитаемее -  ибо без циклов и пр. заморочек.  С датчиков же мы что-то снимаем для дальнейшего анализа или хотя-бы визуализации. А если просто "прочитал - добавил" -  то можно и без numpy забивать память, пока не произойдет переполнение.

Comment: @passant Ну да, поскольку сценарий использования автором описан не целиком, сложновато гадать. Но судя по тому, как он пытается использовать `numpy`, скорее всего тут речь не идёт о векторной/матричной обработке данных, при которой `numpy` смог бы раскрыться.

Comment: @CrazyElf Данные после чтения мне необходимо обрабатывать. Сама математика не сложная, но всё равно присутствует. И графики также необходимо строить, поэтому всё таки воспользуюсь советом и буду использовать  `numpy`. Спасибо всем за советы!)

Comment: Отличная идея с очередями - они здесь архитектурно лучше всего подходят, по-моему

Answer (score 2):

Массив не изменяем

```
import numpy as np

my_array = np.array(['a', 'd'])
my_array2 =  np.append(my_array, 'w', )
print(my_array)
print(my_array2)
```

Использование np.append :

```
my_array  = np.array([0])
for i in range(int(10)):
    my_array = np.append(my_array , i)
```

Использование python преобразования списка в массив после этого:

```
my_list= [0]
for k in range(int(10)):
    my_array.append(k)
my_array = np.array(my_array )
```

Предварительное выделение массива numpy:

```
e = np.zeros((n,))
for k in range(n):
    e[k] = k
```

Comment: а если подумать и присвоить результат append самому себе? или вы при каждом чихе будете новый массив создавать?

Comment: это в качестве примера! понятно, что имя можно одно и тоже

Comment: @АндрейКрузлик А как будет более оптимально, сначала сохранять значение в обычный список пайтон, а потом преобразовывать в массив NumPy или сразу записывать в массив таким образом: `my_array = np.append(my_array, 12)`?

Comment: преобразования списка в массив будет быстрее работать